# retrofit 2 @path Vs @query

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I am new to retrofit 2 library.I read several articles to get started as a beginner and I managed to fetch XML data from my RESTful API without specifying parameters.In my method that generated the XML resource is below.

```
@GET
@Path("/foods")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<FoodPyramid> getFoodPyramid() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    trans = session.beginTransaction();
    List<FoodPyramid> foodList = session.createQuery("from FoodPyramid").list();
    try {
        trans.commit();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.close();
        System.err.println("Food Pyramid fetch " + e);
    }
    System.err.println("Am in the food modal. . . . . . . .");
    return foodList;
}
```

Now when I tried to pass parameter in the interface

```
@GET("user/{username}/{password}")
Call<List<UserCredentail>> getUserOuth(@Query("username") String username, @Query("password") String password);
```

It failed to run,no data was receive by a client . It took me a week trying to fix it though by using a non parameter call fetched the resources;
So tried to change it to:

```
@GET("user/{username}/{password}")
Call<List<UserCredentail>> getUserOuth(@Path("username") String username, @Path("password") String password);
```

and it worked fine. So My question is: When do I need to use `@Query` and `@Path` Annotation in retrofit 2?

Answer (score 283):

Consider this is the url:

`www.app.net/api/searchtypes/862189/filters?Type=6&SearchText=School`

Now this is the call:

```
@GET("/api/searchtypes/{Id}/filters")
Call<FilterResponse> getFilterList(
          @Path("Id") long customerId,
          @Query("Type") String responseType,
          @Query("SearchText") String searchText
);
```

So we have:

```
www.app.net/api/searchtypes/{Path}/filters?Type={Query}&SearchText={Query}
```

Things that come after the **?** are usually queries.

Comment: Helped me alot as well! There is difference between query and path

Comment: then what is & mean in this url? and in url type={query} but in @query("type") sting responsetype , so how =  sign is inserted in this url? i confused about this issue

Answer (score 28):

For example:

```
@GET("/user/{username}?type={admin}")
```

Here `username` is the `path` variable, and `type` is the query variable

```
@GET("/user/{username}?type={admin}")
void getUserOuth(@Path("username") String username, @Query("type") String type)
```

Comment: Doesn't it require to be **type** instead of **admin** as _@Query_ parameter?
As:
`void getUserOuth(@Path("username") String username, @Query("type") String type)`

Answer (score 9):

**Kotlin Answer**

For example, geting specific post from list with post id:

```
@GET("Posts/{post_id}")
suspend fun getPost(@Path("post_id") postId: String): Response<Post>
```

*Note: In this example, Post is my data model class.*

Answer (score 7):

`@Query`

- This annotation represents any query key value pair to be sent along with the network request

`@Path`

- This annotation implies that the passed parameter will be swapped in the endpoint path

Answer (score 4):

@Path annotation use for ordering parameters as your own way. And defined the order in url.

```
@GET("user/{username}/{password}")
Call<List<UserCredentail>> getUserOuth(@Path("username") String username, @Path("password") String password);
```

@Query annotation auto order of parameters and added with url including "?" symbol.

```
   @GET("user")
    Call<List<UserCredentail>> getUserOuth(@Query("username") String username, @Query("password") String password);
```

Answer (score 4):

Path is use to replace item defined in your path, like

```
@POST("setting/update_notification_status/{c_notification_id}")
Call<JsonObject> updateNotificationStatus(@Header("Sessionkey") String token, @Path("c_notification_id") String c_notification_id );
```

Answer (score 3):

@Path is used when you have url which has '/'  dynamic value after a backword slash.Example "http://google.com/index.html/userid. So in this url /userid is dynamic so to access this url  your request should be
@Get("index.html/{userid}")
Calldata(@Path("userid")int id);

@Query is used when you have a url which has '?' dynamic value after a question mark.Example "http://google.com/index.html?userid.So in this url ? userid is dynamic so to access this url  your request should be
@Get("index.html")
Calldata(@Query("userid")int id);

Answer (score 2):

Query is use for URL parameters and with @Query("password") the URL should be :

```
user/john?password=****
```

Path is use to replace item defined in your path, like

```
user/{username}
```